# ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCDIFADDR): Can't assign requested address

Tags: networking, routing

I have a Macbook Air (M1, 2020) with macOs Big Sur installed. I just wiped my device and reinstalled the OS. What I want to do, is change, remove or add interfaces, but I can't.
Evertime I try to change something `ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCDIFADDR): Can't assign requested address` appears.

I already tried

```
sudo ifconfig [interface] down
sudo route flush
sudo ifconfig [interface] up
```

Doesn't change anything.

Here's my `ifconfig` output:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
anpi0: flags=8822<BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 1e:29:40:24:74:78 
    inet6 fe80::1c29:40ff:fe24:7478%anpi0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
anpi1: flags=8822<BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 1e:29:40:24:74:79 
    inet6 fe80::1c29:40ff:fe24:7479%anpi1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
ap1: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 3a:3e:ef:dd:ff:1c 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
en3: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 1e:29:40:24:74:58 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
en5: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 1e:29:40:24:74:59 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: none
    status: inactive
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 18:3e:ef:dd:ff:1c 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8822<BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 36:70:27:78:e3:80 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8822<BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 36:70:27:78:e3:84 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8902<BROADCAST,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 1e:b0:66:eb:50:ac 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
llw0: flags=8822<BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 1e:b0:66:eb:50:ac 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
utun2: flags=8050<POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::c171:924:274f:c2a1%utun2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x13 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun3: flags=8050<POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::6422:e4c5:67c3:5e9c%utun3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x14 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
en4: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=6467<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 00:e0:4c:68:04:bb 
    inet6 fe80::1cb8:705d:659f:c6d7%en4 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x8 
    inet6 2a02:2454:5b0:7c00:c06:118c:8e39:515d prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
    inet6 2a02:2454:5b0:7c00:14a3:cad1:473a:7f25 prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
    inet 192.168.0.5 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
```

And here's my routing table (remember, immediately after I reinstalled the OS!):

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.1        UGScg          en4       
127                localhost          UCS            lo0       
localhost          localhost          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#8             UCS            en4      !
192.168.0          link#8             UCS            en4      !
192.168.0.1/32     link#8             UCS            en4      !
192.168.0.1        dc:53:7c:77:30:b8  UHLWIir        en4   1134
192.168.0.5/32     link#8             UCS            en4      !
224.0.0/4          link#8             UmCS           en4      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en4       
255.255.255.255/32 link#8             UCS            en4      !

Internet6:
Destination        Gateway            Flags         Netif Expire
default            fe80::de53:7cff:fe UGcg            en4       
localhost          localhost          UHL             lo0       
2a02-2454-5b0-7c00 link#8             UC              en4       
2a02-2454-5b0-7c00 fe80::de53:7cff:fe UGc             en4       
2a02-2454-5b0-7c00 0:e0:4c:68:4:bb    UHL             lo0       
2a02-2454-5b0-7c00 0:e0:4c:68:4:bb    UHL             lo0       
2a02-2454-5b0-7c00 link#8             UHLWI           en4       
fe80::%lo0         fe80::1%lo0        UcI             lo0       
fe80::1%lo0        link#1             UHLI            lo0       
fe80::%anpi0       link#4             UCI           anpi0       
fe80::1c29:40ff:fe 1e:29:40:24:74:78  UHLI            lo0       
fe80::%anpi1       link#5             UCI           anpi1       
fe80::1c29:40ff:fe 1e:29:40:24:74:79  UHLI            lo0       
fe80::%en4         link#8             UCI             en4       
fe80::1cb8:705d:65 0:e0:4c:68:4:bb    UHLI            lo0       
fe80::de53:7cff:fe dc:53:7c:77:30:b8  UHLWIir         en4       
fe80::%utun2       fe80::c171:924:274 UcI           utun2       
fe80::c171:924:274 link#19            UHLI            lo0       
fe80::%utun3       fe80::6422:e4c5:67 UcI           utun3       
fe80::6422:e4c5:67 link#20            UHLI            lo0       
ff00::             localhost          UmCI            lo0       
ff00::             link#4             UmCI          anpi0       
ff00::             link#5             UmCI          anpi1       
ff00::             link#8             UmCI            en4       
ff00::             link#14            UmCI          awdl0       
ff00::             link#15            UmCI           llw0       
ff00::             fe80::c171:924:274 UmCI          utun2       
ff00::             fe80::6422:e4c5:67 UmCI          utun3       
ff01::%lo0         localhost          UmCI            lo0       
ff01::%anpi0       link#4             UmCI          anpi0       
ff01::%anpi1       link#5             UmCI          anpi1       
ff01::%en4         link#8             UmCI            en4       
ff01::%awdl0       link#14            UmCI          awdl0       
ff01::%llw0        link#15            UmCI           llw0       
ff01::%utun2       fe80::c171:924:274 UmCI          utun2       
ff01::%utun3       fe80::6422:e4c5:67 UmCI          utun3       
ff02::%lo0         localhost          UmCI            lo0       
ff02::%anpi0       link#4             UmCI          anpi0       
ff02::%anpi1       link#5             UmCI          anpi1       
ff02::%en4         link#8             UmCI            en4       
ff02::%awdl0       link#14            UmCI          awdl0       
ff02::%llw0        link#15            UmCI           llw0       
ff02::%utun2       fe80::c171:924:274 UmCI          utun2       
ff02::%utun3       fe80::6422:e4c5:67 UmCI          utun3
```

Any suggestions what I could try to circumvent this error or what's going on on my network?